# Get the file name from a image source using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the name of an image in an HTML page not the full path using javascript.
For example, if the image path is www.dds.com/images/1.jpg 
I need to get the only 1.jpg from the full path.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get it like this

```
filename = path.split("/")[path.split("/").length-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've already gotten the image path, you can find the last `/` and get whatever is after it ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4q2dL/)):

```
var index = path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
var filename = path.substr(index);
```